# HTML JS - sub menu is not working?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to achieve [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjvtB.png). But I could not succeed so far. My code is given below. What is wrong with it?

**html:**

```
<nav id="bt-menu" class="bt-menu">
                <a href="#" class="bt-menu-trigger" id="bt-icon icon-gplus" ><br><span>Menu
                <ul > 
                        <li style="text-align:center;"><a href="index.php"><span>DashBoard</span></a></li>
                        <li style="text-align:center;"><a href="user.php"><span>User </span></a></li>
                        <li style="text-align:center;"><a href="candidates.php"><span>Candidates</span></a></li>
                        <li style="text-align:center;"><a href="party.php"><span>Partylist</span></a></li>
                        <li style="text-align:center;"><a href="position.php"><span>Position</span></a></li>
                        <li style="text-align:center;"><a href="program.php"><span>Program</span></a></li>
                        <li style="text-align:center;"><a href="department.php"><span>Department</span></a></li>
                        <li style="text-align:center;"class="active"><a href="syear.php"><span>School-Year</span></a></li>
                        <li style="text-align:center;"><a href="reports.php"><span>Reports</span></a></li>
                        <li style="text-align:center;"><a href="#"><span>Logs</span></a>
         <ul class="sub-menu" style="text-align:right">
        <li><a href="#" style="text-align:right;">Submenu</a></li>
            </ul></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('li a').click(
function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
})
  </script>
```

Comment: your `bt-menu-trigger` a and span doesn't have closing tag

Answer (score 0):

Firstly correct your markup ,some tags are not properly closed.

Second, you need to use `preventDefault()` to disable the default action of the `a` tag.

Third,

```
$('li a').click(
function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
})
```

this code will toggle you menu only if next element is the menu itself.

so use this

```
 $('li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('a:contains(Submenu)').slideToggle();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uc3hp4o5/

Comment: or what if I its an open and close submenu?